# compare string element with numeric

Tags: c++, string, compare

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string s("092282");
    cout << s[0];
    if (s[0] < (char)9)
    {
        cout << "yesss";
    }
}
```

In this text I am not able to understand how to compare string element which is numeric constant and a numeric.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what you don't understand?  I don't understand what you don't understand about the above code.

Comment: What do you expect '(char)9' to do? Using the cast operator doesn't do what you expect

Comment: `s[0]` is a char, if you want to compare it with numeric digit, do it like this: `if (s[0] - '0' < 9)`

Comment: @kiner_shah: Or simply: `if (s[0] < '9')` ?

Comment: i didn't get you kiner.what have you written there

Comment: Side note: be careful with your [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: @sparshgoil You need to understand the difference between an integer like `9` and a character like `'9'`. Even through your string is all numbers it's made up of characters not integers. So the correct comparison is `if (s[0] < '9')` as JVApen said.

Comment: @sparshgoil, characters '0', '1', ..., '9', have ASCII values 48, 49,..., 57. You can read about ASCII [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Comment: @JVApen That returns true for characters like `!`, among others. You should use `std::isdigit` instead.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Agreed, however, it ain't undefined behavior like the `s[0] - '0'`at some platforms.

Comment: @JVApen No but it will give the wrong answer. Why's `s[0] - '0'` UB?

Comment: Because char, depending on the platform is signed or unsigned. Signed overflow is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To can compare characters with intergers but `char c = '9'` is encoded as integer using ASCII table standard. In this table character `'9'` is equal to 57. You can simply check this.

```
if('9' == (char)57)
    cout << "yes";
```

output:

```
yes
```

Change your code as below:

```
int main() 
{
    string s("092282");
    cout << s[0] << endl;
    if (s[0] < '9')
    {
        cout << "yesss";
    }
}
```

Comment: You **can** compare characters with integers. You have to be careful that the values you're dealing with are appropriate. And for the comparison `if ('9' == (char)57)` the cast is superfluous; `if ('9' == 57)` does the same thing. Both values will be converted to `int` for the comparison.

Comment: Note that using ASCII is quite common, but not required.

Comment: Actually just noticed that's the OP's bug not yours so no downvote